# How to increase initialization speed of multiple Selectmenus in jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm building dynamically a large form (~200 selects) with js, appending it to the DOM and using jquery UI selectmenus.

Jquery UI selectmenus are initialized with :

```
$('#my_form_id').selectmenu();
```

It takes between 800 and 1000 ms to be processed.

Any idea on how to make it faster ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, it's just slow due to the amount of elements in the DOM which need updating/creating. There's not much you can do other than use a different library, or write your own that doesn't use jQuery

Comment: ... Or lazy load the page so that you're not setting 200 selects at once.

Comment: thank you. Jquery UI adds a lot of lines in the DOM so I guess the slow down is indeed inevitable. I've changed the code to remove it and it works perfectly now. Vanilla JS is still the best for performance ;-)